# How can you make shortest line touching two circles at any given space?

Tags: math, d3.js, trigonometry

Here is what I want to achieve.

[image]

The parameters are both circles radius, x - centers, and y - centers. The function to make line is `line(x1, y1, x2, y2)`.

Here is what I have now using JavaScript.

```
var lineX1 = circleX1 + (circleRadius1 * Math.sin(Math.atan2(circleY2 - circleY1, circleX2 - circleX1)));
var lineY1 = circleY1 + (circleRadius1 * Math.cos(Math.atan2(circleY2 - circleY1, circleX2 - circleX1)));
var lineX2 = circleX2 - (circleRadius2 * Math.sin(Math.atan2(circleY1 - circleY2, circleX1 - circleX2)));
var lineY2 = circleY2 - (circleRadius2 * Math.cos(Math.atan2(circleY1 - circleY2, circleX1 - circleX2)));

line(lineX1, lineY1, lineX2, lineY2);
```

But it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Are you calling `Math.atan()` (i.e., one-parameter method) but intending to call `Math.atan2()` (i.e., two-parameter method)?

Comment: It was a typo, I used `Math.atan2()` as well. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct.  As @welbog pointed out, you want to use [Math.atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2).  Also, you swapped your cos and sin for the x/y.  Finally, you only need to calculate the angle once.

Here's a demonstration:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500);
      
    draw();

    function draw() {
      
      svg.selectAll("*").remove();

      var circleRadius1 = Math.random() * 100,
        circleRadius2 = Math.random() * 100,
        circleX1 = Math.random() * 500,
        circleY1 = Math.random() * 500,
        circleX2 = Math.random() * 500,
        circleY2 = Math.random() * 500;
        
      svg.append('circle')
        .attr('r', circleRadius1)
        .attr('cx', circleX1)
        .attr('cy', circleY1)
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
        
      svg.append('circle')
        .attr('r', circleRadius2)
        .attr('cx', circleX2)
        .attr('cy', circleY2)
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .style('stroke', 'orange');
        
      var angle = Math.atan2(circleY2 - circleY1, circleX2 - circleX1),
          lineX1 = circleX1 + (circleRadius1 * Math.cos(angle)),
          lineY1 = circleY1 + (circleRadius1 * Math.sin(angle)),
          lineX2 = circleX2 - (circleRadius2 * Math.cos(angle)),
          lineY2 = circleY2 - (circleRadius2 * Math.sin(angle));
          
      svg.append('line')
        .attr('x1', lineX1)
        .attr('y1', lineY1)
        .attr('x2', lineX2)
        .attr('y2', lineY2)
        .style('stroke','black')
        
      setTimeout(draw, 1000);

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oooh. Alright, the problem was actually because I flipped the cos and sin. The `Math.atan()` was a type since I used  `Math.atan2()` as well. All in all thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

There is no need in trigonometric functions.

```
center difference vector
dx = cx2 - cx1
dy = cy2 - cy1
len = Math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
normalized
udx = dx / len
udy = dy / len

line ends
lx1 = cx1 + udx * r1
ly1 = cy1 + udy * r1
lx2 = cx2 - udx * r2
ly2 = cy2 - udy * r2
```

Comment: Upvoted, but there is no `Math.Sqrt()` in JavaScript. It's `math.sqrt()`.

Comment: I don't know such JavaScript peculiarities, so gave a kind of pseudocode.